# Getting functions of inherited functions to be called

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say I have a base class `Animal` from which a class `Cow` inherits, and a `Barn` class containing an `Animal` vector, and let's say the Animal class has a virtual function `scream()`, which `Cow` overrides.

With the following code:

Animal.h

```
#ifndef _ANIMAL_H
#define _ANIMAL_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal {
public:
    Animal() {};
    virtual void scream() {cout << "aaaAAAAAAAAAAGHHHHHHHHHH!!! ahhh..." << endl;}
};

#endif  /* _ANIMAL_H */
```

Cow.h

```
#ifndef _COW_H
#define _COW_H

#include "Animal.h"

class Cow: public Animal {
public:
    Cow() {}
    void scream() {cout << "MOOooooOOOOOOOO!!!" << endl;}
};

#endif  /* _COW_H */
```

Barn.h

```
#ifndef _BARN_H
#define _BARN_H

#include "Animal.h"
#include <vector>

class Barn {
    std::vector<Animal> animals;

public:
    Barn() {}
    void insertAnimal(Animal animal) {animals.push_back(animal);}
    void tortureAnimals() {
        for(int a = 0; a < animals.size(); a++)
            animals[a].scream();
    }
};

#endif  /* _BARN_H */
```

and finally main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Barn.h"
#include "Cow.h"
#include "Chicken.h"

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Barn barn;
    barn.insertAnimal(Cow());
    barn.tortureAnimals();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I get this output:

```
aaaAAAAAAAAAAGHHHHHHHHHH!!! ahhh...
```

How should I code this to get `MOOooooOOOOOOOO!!!` (and whatever other classes inheriting `Animal` wants `scream()` to be) instead?

Comment: nice example code! screaming cows makes for an interesting read :) much better than foo and bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification that stores pointers to animals should help:

```
#ifndef _BARN_H
#define _BARN_H

#include "Animal.h"
#include <vector>

class Barn {
    std::vector<Animal *> animals;

public:
    Barn() {}
    void insertAnimal(Animal *animal) {animals.push_back(animal);}
    void tortureAnimals() {
        for(int a = 0; a < animals.size(); a++)
            animals[a]->scream();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Barn barn;
    barn.insertAnimal(new Cow());
    barn.tortureAnimals();

    // should clean up barn contents here...

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Err.. you have to delete those. Perhaps `boost::ptr_vector` or `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr>`, or you'll have to have a for loop deleting the things....

Comment: @Billy ONeal, yes I was editing in a comment to that effect.  The boost pointers would be a better approach, but required more editing to the example.  I felt this would get the point across for how to deploy polymorphism.

Comment: Indeed, it would be quite cruel to first torture the animals and then simply forgetting about them... release the poor creatures!

Answer (score 12):

A `std::vector<Animal>` can only contain `Animal` objects, not `Cow` objects.

Here's what happens when you say `barn.insertAnimal(Cow());`:

1. A temporary object of type Cow is created by the evaluation of `Cow()`.
2. The parameter `animal` is copy-constructed from that temporary cow since you chose to pass it by value. This `animal` is a copy of the `Animal`-part of the temporary cow. This is called *object-slicing*.
3. The next element in the vector is copy-constructed from the parameter `animal`. Now you already have one cow and two additional animals, but you only wanted one cow!
4. The parameter `animal` is destroyed because `insertBarn` returns.
5. The temporary cow is destroyed because evaluation has reached the semicolon at the end of the line (to be more precise: evaluation of the full-expression has completed).

What is the lesson here? Don't pass animals by value, and don't store animals by value. 
Runtime polymorphism requires a level of indirection. You probably want a `std::vector<Animal*>` or `std::vector<shared_ptr<Animal> >` or `boost::ptr_vector<Animal>`.

Comment: To clarify: Your vector needs to hold pointers because it suffers from the slicing problem when you hold actual objects in it.

Comment: So did my `Cow` get degraded to a mere `Animal`?

Comment: @wrong: Kinda -- the `Animal` part of your `Cow` was *copied* into the vector.

Comment: I would advice against a vector of pointers. Rather use a boost:ptr_vector<Animal> this is a container specifically designed to hold pointers and manage their lifespan. Alternatively use a vector of shared pointers to Animal.

Comment: Heh: the `boost::ptr_vector<>` tutorial even uses the 'Animal' hierarchy for its examples (no Cows, though): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: @FredOverflow: I have corrected *copy of the `Cow`-part of the temporary cow* to *copy of the `Animal`-part of the temporary cow*. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: `This is called object-slicing.` This is even better than tortureAnimals() LOL!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing pass-by-value, so `Cow` is being made into `Animal`.

Using Animal * instead works, though this has memory leaks:

```
class Barn {
    std::vector<Animal *> animals;

    void insertAnimal(Animal *animal) {animals.push_back(animal);}

    void tortureAnimals() {
        for(int a = 0; a < animals.size(); a++)
            animals[a]->scream();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Barn barn;
    Cow *c = new Cow();
    barn.insertAnimal(c);
    barn.tortureAnimals();
    /* delete them here... */
}
```

Comment: @Martin: Actually, `&Cow()` is illegal in standard C++ because the address-operator can only be applied to lvalues. And even if some perverted compiler allows it, the temporary cow does not exist in the line `barn.tortureAnimals();` anymore!